# The order of attributes gets messed up

Tags: android, sqlite, attributes, tuples, android-sqlite

In Android SQLite, I am trying to get some details of customers when I am online, store it in SQLite database, and display them when I am offline.

Unfortunately when doing it so, that the order of the columns get unfortunately messed up.
I have the following table, `TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL`:

```
Loan_No text primary key,
agreement_date date,
branch_name text,
loan_status text,
address1 text,
address2 text,
status_type integer,
user_id integer
```

The customer details are displayed like this when I am online:

Example 1:

```
Loan Number: CDAGRTW1412090016
Agreement Date: 12/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
Branch Name:
Loan Status: Expired
Address 1: 9/43, MOTI BAG NAGAL FATHORI YAMUNA BRIDGE
Address 2:
```

Unfortunately, when I am offline, the order of the fields get messed up like this.

Example 1:

```
Loan Number: CDAGRTW1412090016
Agreement Date:
Branch Name: 9/43, MOTI BAG NAGAL FATHORI YAMUNA BRIDGE
Loan Status:
Address 1: Expired
Address 2: 12/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

I would like to know why that it should ever happen so, at all.

Here is my update or insert function call in main activity fragment Java file, that depending upon if whether, within any given case that row already exists or not:

`onResponse()` function call:

```
if (db.selectAgeingvalues(Loan_No, status_type, user_id) == 0) {
    db.insertAgeingvalues(Loan_No, agreement_date, branch_name, loan_status, address1, address2, status_type, user_id);
} else {
    db.updateAgeingvalues(Loan_No, agreement_date, branch_name, loan_status, address1, address2, status_type, user_id);
}
```

Here is my select function call to retrieve details of customers from stored Android SQLite database table when I am offline:

`onFailure()` function call:

```
sqliteDB db = new sqliteDB(getActivity());
List<String> AgeingvaluesList[] = db.selectAgeingvalues("-1", user_id);
for(int i = 0; i < AgeingvaluesList[0].size(); i++)
{
    Loan_No = AgeingvaluesList[0].get(i);
    agreement_date = AgeingvaluesList[1].get(i);
    branch_name = AgeingvaluesList[2].get(i);
    loan_status = AgeingvaluesList[3].get(i);
    address1 = AgeingvaluesList[4].get(i);
    address2 = AgeingvaluesList[5].get(i);
    status_type = AgeingvaluesList[6].get(i);
}
```

Here are my SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, onCreate() and onUpgrade() function calls inside of my own declared `sqliteDB.java` Java file, as follows, as like, such as, those like:

`onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)` function call

in order to be able to be creating a table `TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL` into the stored Android SQLite database table if it already does not exist or dropping it and recreating it if it already exists, based upon following assigned values of variable, `sqLiteDatabase`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
            "create table " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL +
                    "("
                    + "Loan_No text not null unique primary key,"
                    + "branch_name text,"
                    + "address1 text not null,"
                    + "address2 text,"
                    + "loan_status text not null,"
                    + "agreement_date text not null,"
                    + "status_type number not null,"
                    + "user_id text not null"
                    + ")"
    );
}
```

`onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)` function call

in order to be able to be upgrading a table `TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL` into the stored Android SQLite database table if it already exists or not during upgradation of mobile application to a newer version or during uninstallation and reinstallation of mobile application to a newer version, based upon following assigned values of variables, `sqLiteDatabase`, `i` and `i1`:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

`insertAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String agreement_date, String branch_name, String loan_status, String address1, String address2, String status_type, String user_id)` function call

in order to be able to be inserting a row into the stored Android SQLite database table if it already does not exist, based upon following assigned values of variables, `Loan_No`, `agreement_date`, `branch_name`, `loan_status`, `address1`, `address2`, `status_type` and `user_id`:

```
public boolean insertAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String agreement_date, String branch_name, String loan_status, String address1, String address2, String status_type, String user_id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Loan_No", Loan_No);
    contentValues.put("agreement_date", agreement_date);
    contentValues.put("branch_name", branch_name);
    contentValues.put("loan_status", loan_status);
    contentValues.put("address1", address1);
    contentValues.put("address2", address2);
    contentValues.put("status_type", status_type);
    contentValues.put("user_id", user_id);
    db.insert(TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

`updateAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String agreement_date, String branch_name, String loan_status, String address1, String address2, String status_type, String user_id)` function call:

in order to be able to be updating a row into the stored Android SQLite database table if it already exists, based upon following assigned values of variables, `Loan_No`, `agreement_date`, `branch_name`, `loan_status`, `address1`, `address2`, `status_type` and `user_id`:

```
public int updateAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String agreement_date, String branch_name, String loan_status, String address1, String address2, String status_type, String user_id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Loan_No", Loan_No);
    contentValues.put("agreement_date", agreement_date);
    contentValues.put("branch_name", branch_name);
    contentValues.put("loan_status", loan_status);
    contentValues.put("address1", address1);
    contentValues.put("address2", address2);
    contentValues.put("status_type", status_type);
    contentValues.put("user_id", user_id);
    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL, contentValues, "Loan_No = ? AND user_id = ?",
            new String[] {Loan_No, user_id});
}
```

`selectAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String status_type, String user_id)` function call

Android SQLite database table:

```
public int selectAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String status_type, String user_id)
{
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT Loan_No FROM " + TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL + " WHERE user_id = \"" + user_id + "\" AND Loan_No = \"" + Loan_No + "\" AND status_type = " + status_type + ")", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            count = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return count;
}
```

`selectAgeingvalues(String status_type, String user_id)` function call

in order to be able to be retrieving a row from the stored Android SQLite database table if it already exists or not, based upon following assigned values of variables, `status_type` and `user_id`:

```
public List<String>[] selectAgeingvalues(String status_type, String user_id)
{
    String Loan_No;
    String agreement_date;
    String branch_name;
    String loan_status;
    String address1;
    String address2;
    List AgeingvaluesList[] = new List[7];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        AgeingvaluesList[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_AGEING_VALUES_ALL+" WHERE user_id = \""+user_id+"\" AND status_type = "+status_type, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Loan_No = cursor.getString(0);
            AgeingvaluesList[0].add(Loan_No);

            agreement_date = cursor.getString(1);
            AgeingvaluesList[1].add(agreement_date);

            branch_name = cursor.getString(2);
            AgeingvaluesList[2].add(branch_name);

            loan_status = cursor.getString(3);
            AgeingvaluesList[3].add(loan_status);

            address1 = cursor.getString(4);
            AgeingvaluesList[4].add(address1);

            address2 = cursor.getString(5);
            AgeingvaluesList[5].add(address2);

            status_type = cursor.getString(6);
            AgeingvaluesList[6].add(status_type);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return AgeingvaluesList;
}
```

What am I doing wrongly enough?

Comment: I think that I have figured out with that issue.

Comment: `cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No")` returns 0. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("agreement_date")` returns 5. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("branch_name")` returns 1. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("loan_status")` returns 4.
`cursor.getColumnIndex("address1")` returns 2. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("address2")` returns 3. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("status_type")` returns 6. 
`cursor.getColumnIndex("user_id")` returns 7.

Comment: According to the order defined in the stored Android SQLite database table's `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)` function call.

Comment: When you insert or update records into the table, then you do it by using the name of the columns with contentValues.put function call.

Comment: When you select and retrieve records from the table, then doing so with `cursor.getString(index)` rather than, instead of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name))` reflects with the order of the attributes in the stored Android SQLite database table, rather than instead of doing so it by using the name of the columns with `contentValues.put` function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cursor.getString(1);` change it to `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No "));` and do this for all the respective fields.

Always use column name instead of position, because column position can change.
of course column name can change as well but let say if you add a new column and it position between column 1 and column 2. You need to change your code if you use number. But if you use name, you will be fine.

Comment: did you change this?what was the output?and your tables dont help at all,you have just added more unnecessary code

Comment: The required online output and the output that I get whenever that I am offline, have been already clearly given in Example 1 whatever that I have mentioned above already. After all, I am not sure why. After all, I am not sure whether my own committed mistake is in `onResponse`, `onFailure`, `onCreate`, `onUpgrade`, `insertAgeingvalues`, `updateAgeingvalues` or `selectAgeingvalues` function call. Is it not so?

Comment: By the way, why do you call it as unnecessary code. They are pieces of code that are fully needed entirely enough to understand and answer the entire piece of question fully enough. After all, I am not sure why. After all, I am not sure whether my own committed mistake is in `onResponse`, `onFailure`, `onCreate`, `onUpgrade`, `insertAgeingvalues`, `updateAgeingvalues` or `selectAgeingvalues` function call. Is it not so?

Comment: Thank you for your own response. But, sorry that it does not help out at all. After all, that I think that I had missed out crucial portions of my own written code in my own submitted first attempt. Please try out again!

Comment: can you please tell me weather anything changes if you remove the 0 from the list?

Comment: also why do you select only the loan number?

Comment: The order of attributes as part of offline output does not change when I remove 0 from the list. `AgeingvaluesList[0].size()` returns the total number of attributes in the table, which in this case is always a total of 7 for every record in the table, ever in this any given case. By making use of `AgeingvaluesList[].size()`, you are trying out to return the total number of records in the table, which is clearly incorrect enough in this any given case?

Comment: By making use of the same way, where do I ever select only the loan number?

Answer (score 0):

(D.'s original answer, keeping it all for reference purposes only).

I think your problem is in the

```
for(int i = 0; i < AgeingvaluesList[0].size(); i++)
```

With this `AgeingvaluesList[0].size();` you are only getting the size of the first element and that's also the size of the first element!

Change it to `AgeingvaluesList().size();`
also please would you mind instead of `cursor.getString(1);` change it to `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No "));` and do this for all the respective fields

Comment: would you mind do smth can you please print `AgeingvaluesList[0].size()` and `AgeingvaluesList().size()` what is the value of each I would like to see smth. "-1", is the offline status? also would you mind instead of `cursor.getString(1)`; change it to `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No "));`

Comment: In `selectAgeingvalues(String status_type, String user_id)` function call, there are 8 total different possible columns available but I am selecting only 7 of them, excluding the needless `user_id` column for offline output displaying sakes and purposes.

Comment: can you please make the changes that I have suggested above and tell me?

Comment: `AgeingvaluesList[0].size()` returns 7, the total number of columns selected, 7 out of 8 total different possible columns available, for offline output displaying sakes and purposes in total. `AgeingvaluesList[].size()` returns 2044, the total number of records in the stored Android SQLite database table.

Comment: okay what about also would you mind instead of `cursor.getString(1)`; change it to `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No "));` does this change the order?

Comment: "-1" is not the offline status. There are 3 different status types: -1 for Pending, 1 for Planned and 3 for Completed, for details of customers and their own schedules to visits.

Comment: Instead of using `cursor.getString(0)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No"))` returns CDAGRTW1412090016 correctly. By the way, please note that, `Loan_No` corresponds to `cursor.getString(0)` and not `cursor.getString(1)`.

Comment: `Loan_No` seems to be correctly displayed because its own order is unaffected in the offline output displaying sakes and purposes. Should I do it for the other columns as well as like, such as those like, `agreement_date`, `branch_name`, `loan_status`, `address1` and `address2`, excluding off away within `status_type` and `user_id` for the offline output displaying sakes and purposes?

Comment: By the way, is this in the `selectAgeingvalues(String status_type, String user_id)` function call?

Comment: change it first here `public int selectAgeingvalues(String Loan_No, String status_type, String user_id)` ...see if anything changed then change also the second one `public List<String>[] selectAgeingvalues(String status_type, String user_id)`

Comment: Instead of using `cursor.getString(0)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Loan_No"))` returns CDAGRTW1412090016 correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(1)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("agreement_date"))` returns 12/9/2014 12:00:00 AM correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(2)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("branch_name"))` returns null correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(3)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("loan_status"))` returns Expired correctly.

Comment: Instead of using `cursor.getString(4)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address1"))` returns 9/43, MOTI BAG NAGAL FATHORI YAMUNA BRIDGE correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(5)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address2"))` returns null correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(6)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status_type"))` returns -1 correctly. Instead of using `cursor.getString(7)`, making use of `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_id"))` returns 15 correctly.

Comment: And also that was the reason why every function that I had included was important enough.

Comment: You originally and initially decided to discard away off with some of them as unnecessary pieces of code and unneeded pieces of code.